# How to solve: curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Tags: software-installation, curl, output, rclone

I am really new to Ubuntu (22.04.1 LTS) and I would like to install Rclone using the command described in their installation page: https://rclone.org/install/

```
sudo -v ; curl https://rclone.org/install.sh | sudo bash -s beta
```

Unfortunately I get the error message below:

```
~$ sudo -v ; curl https://rclone.org/install.sh | sudo bash
[sudo] password for daniele: 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4631  100  4631    0     0  10767      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10794
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

Do you have any ideas how I could avoid this Failure? I am in my home directory and I have root permissions.

Comment: problem is inside the script not the curl command used so you will need to examine that ;)  The script was made for 18.04(?) If so you might need a better source for 22.04

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind, I eventually found out that I had to install curl: `sudo apt install curl`